# JSON POST and GET 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, django, api

I am trying to create an API in Django but am receiving the following errors message in the JavaScript console.

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/undefined 404 (Not Found)
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

API url: `path("edit/<int:post_id>", views.edit, name="edit")`

views.py

```
def edit(request, post_id):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(user=request.user, pk=post_id)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Post does not exist."}, status=404)

    if request.method == "GET":
        return JsonResponse(post.serialize())
    else:  
        return JsonResponse({"error": "Need a GET request."}, status=404)
```

JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    const editButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.edit_button');
    for (const button of editButtons) {
      button.addEventListener('click', () => edit_email());
    }
  });

function edit_email(id){
    console.log("edit button is clicked")
    document.querySelector('#post_itself').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#date_and_time').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#likes').style.display = 'none';

    const textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    //get post
    fetch(`/edit/${id}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(post => {
        textarea.innerHTML =   `${post.post}`
        document.querySelector('#p_user').append(textarea);
    })

    //save the post
    fetch(`/edit/${id}`,{
        method: 'POST',
        post: JSON.stringify({
            post: textarea.value
        })
    })
}
```

HTML

```
{% for post in page_obj.object_list %}
            <div class = "individual_posts">
                <a href="{% url 'username' post.user %}"><h5 id="p_user" class = "post_user">{{ post.user }}</h5></a>
                <h6 id = "post_itself">{{ post.post }}</h6>
                <h6 id="date_and_time" class = "post_elements">{{ post.date_and_time }}</h6>
                <h6 id="likes" class = "post_elements">{{ post.likes }}&#x1F44D;</h6>
                {% if post.user == request.user %}
                    <button id="editButton" class="edit_button">Edit</button>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

I think something might be wrong in the way I am passing in the id to the API, but I am not sure. Could the for loop in the HTML be causing the problem?

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="users_followers", symmetrical=False)
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name ="who_user_is_following", symmetrical=False)

    def serialize(self):
        return{
            "followers": self.followers,
            "following": self.following
        }

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def serialize(self):
        return{
            "id": self.id,
            "post": self.post,
            "user": self.user,
            "likes": self.likes,
            "date_and_time": self.date_and_time
        }
```

Comment: I'm guessing that the id value is not `undefined`

Comment: @Pointy, how do I define the id value?

Comment: How is the `edit_email` function called?

Comment: Also id values have to be **unique** across the page. You cannot re-use them.

Comment: @Pointy, I am using a addEventListener, which I added to the code in my question. Is there a way to pass the id from the Django model which would be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you call edit_email without id here:

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => edit_email());
```

of cause, after call you get `/edit/undefined` on this line:

```
fetch(`/edit/${id}`)
```

you don't send anything like `id`, I can imagine it should be something like this:

```
button.addEventListener('click', (event) => edit_email(event.target.value));
```

You will also need to pass the value property to the button as post.id assuming that the post object will have an id key in your for loop.

If you are getting a reference error you need to check if page_obj.object_list has an id key for all the posts.

Comment: what can I out for the id so that it gets the id of the Django object? If I put id or post.id, I receive a ReferenceError in the console.

Comment: @HarshGupta, do you know how I could access the id through the Django object? Or is that not possible and I'll have to go about it some other way?

Comment: In html Probably so: <Button value={{post.id}}>

Comment: I added the button value to my code and changed my code to this ```id = button.value;
      button.addEventListener('click', () => edit_email(id));```, but I am still getting the POST error and ```GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/2 500 (Internal Server Error)```. Do you know what could be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: 500 is Not 404. Which Error Message?

Comment: I am receiving three errors: ```network.js:26          POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/2 404 (Not Found)```, ```GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/edit/2 500 (Internal Server Error)```, and ```Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)
edit_email @ network.js:20
(anonymous) @ network.js:5```. I have also added a console.log for the post.id and get the same value for any of the buttons clicked.

Comment: It means, Yor json from fetch ist Not correct. Here you need to debug and See, why json ist wrong. Yor First question (404) is anderes - the View is called with PK.

Comment: It wouldn't be `event.target.value`, it would be `event.target.id`

Comment: @MaximDanilov, I am creating the JSON myself. Do you know if there are any documentations or articles that could help me find the problem with the JSON and fetch?

Comment: @Pointy, your are wrong in this case: target.id is "editButton". And econo want post.id. i write it in commentary <Button ... value={{post.id}}>

Comment: @MaximDanilov, I am also receiving this error in command prompt: ```raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type User is not JSON serializable``` if you know any way to fix it or what could be wrong.

Comment: Try to read about DjangoJSONEncoder, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

Comment: @MaximDanilov, would you mind looking at how I am converting the Django objects to JSON? I have added my models to the question and think it fits into the normal way to serialize JSON unless I have to write a custom JSON encoder.

Comment: i understand now:  for every foreign wrap object  in str, example: "user": str(self.user) or  take pk, example: "user": self.user.pk. Serializer don't know, how to work with Django objects.

Comment: @MaximDanilov, I am not sure what you are trying to say. How should I be serializing the Django objects to JSON?

Comment: class Post(models.Model):
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            "post":  str(self.post),
            "user": self.user.pk,
        }